# DockedItems not displayed in preview

Tags: toolbar, sencha-touch-2, formpanel

Any idea why the docked items not displayed in the preview? Here is the code.

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady:function(){
        var top_toolbar= [{
            xtype:'toolbar',
            ui:'dark',
            dock:'top',
            title:'Login Form'
        }]
        var loginForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            items:[{
                xtype:'fieldset',
                items:[{
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    label:'Username',
                    name:'u_name',
                    labelWidth:100
                },{
                    xtype:'passwordfield',
                    label:'Password',
                    name:'u_password',
                    labelWidth:100
                }]
            }]
        });
        var formPanel=new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen:'true',
            layout:'fit',
            dockedItems:top_toolbar,
            items:[loginForm]
        });
    }
});
```

I am just trying to create a login page, with the textfields for username and password and need to include the toolbar docked on top which has the title 'Login Form'. In the preview i get the textfields with label but it does not show the toolbar. am I doing anything wrong with the code?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dockedItems` configuration has been deprecated in Sencha Touch 2. If you are using a version of the framework which does not include the compatibility layer, that configuration will not work.

Instead, put all items, including docked items, inside the `items` array.

Some other notes:

- `dock` has been changed to `docked`
- `Ext.form.FormPanel` has changed to `Ext.form.Panel`
- You should use `Ext.create()` instead of the the `new` keyword. This means you can take advantage of Ext.Loader and dependency management. You can find our more information about it here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/class_system

And finally, here is how your code should look if you implement all these changes:

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady:function(){
        var loginForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            label: 'Username',
                            name: 'u_name',
                            labelWidth: 100
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'passwordfield',
                            label: 'Password',
                            name: 'u_password',
                            labelWidth: 100
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            fullscreen:'true',
            layout:'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    ui: 'dark',
                    docked: 'top',
                    title: 'Login Form'
                },
                loginForm
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.